# Hugging Face Mozilla Common Voice data structure for wav2vec

Tags: huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I've creaded a low resource datset for ASR. All the audio files are in the sequence 1.mp3, 2.mp3 ..n.mp3.The sentences along with the path (of audio), age, etc are inside a csv column. When trying to use the collab notebook from the [huggingface blog](https://huggingface.co/blog/fine-tune-xlsr-wav2vec2), they seems to have an extra 'audio' column with [extra information](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.14.5/en/audio_dataset)

Anyway how do I add these 'audio' column in my csv?